# in JavaScript how can I loop through data from an asmx web service? (serialized by a JavaScriptSerializer)

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, web

My .asmx web service is returning pairs of file paths and file names like this:

```
[{"thumb":"path/image01_thumb.jpg","image":"path/image01.jpg"},{"thumb":"path/image01_thumb.jpg","image":"path/image01.jpg"}.....etc ]
```

I'm trying to loop through the response and get the properties `thumb` and `image` for each element but all my attempts below have failed me.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "mywebservice",
   data: "{'startpath':'somepath'}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   async: false,
   success: function (msg) {
      $.each (msg, function (m) {
         console.log("alert 3   " + m.thumb);   // output: undefined
         console.log("alert 4   " + m.image);   // output: undefined
   });
}
```

Further debuging...

```
console.log("alert 1   " + msg); //output: [object object]
console.log("alert 2   " + msg.d); //output: the entire response
```

How can I loop through the response and get the values mentioned above. I'm getting the same outcome in chrome and IE 9. Stuck using Jquery 1.3.2 Because I'm using the galleriffic library.

Comment: It's an array of some object. How can you loop an array in JavaScript? Break the problem down into small pieces ..

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON string, parse it to an object.

```
var anObject = JSON.parse(msg);
```

Then you can reference the items and their attributes

```
anObject[i].thumb
```

Comment: There is no need for `JSON.parse` as it comes from a `dataType: 'json'` request - jQuery does that.